# Azure keyvault gives: [TokenExpired] Error validating token: 'S2S12086'

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

On the server the azure key-vault connection in the web app works fine but constantly throws an error-
**{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"[TokenExpired] Error validating token: 'S2S12086'."}}**.

Right now the web-app is being restarted whenever the azure key-vault connection fails.

Packages used to for Azure keyvault connection :
@azure/identity[version 2.0.4]
@azure/keyvault-secrets[version 4.3.0]

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: could you share some code ? I would imagine that there is an out of the box retry policy when the token expired.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this issue recently, there appears to be a regression in the @azure/identity package as of version 2.1.0 that is causing this issue.

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/22722 for context.